# async.js - right method for probing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I have doubts on selecting [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) method for probing several alternatives and stop when the first of them is successful.

For example:

```
async.probeSeries([
    function (callback) {
        // try something and call callback
        // without arguments - probing fails
        callback();
    },
    function (callback) {
        // try something and call callback
        // with arguments - probing successful
        callback(null, ok);
    },
    function (callback) {
        // will be not executed, because
        // the second one is successful
        callback();
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // handle the result returned by the second probe
});
```

I think that using [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) and return the result as error way may be a workaround but is there a better way?

Comment: I think the `async.series` solution would be fine, but result in code that was marginally harder to read. How about putting your alternative functions into an array and using `async.doWhilst()`?

Comment: thank you for the hint with array of functions - I probably put all the functions in to the array and then call detect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [`detectSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#detectseriesarr-iterator-callback)? It works a littlebit different than your example as it checks values from an array with the same function and then callbacks with one of these values, but maybe you can apply it to your problem.

Btw, this looks like the perfect use case for a promise library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/), where you'd write

```
probe1().fail(probe2).fail(probe3).done(resulthandler, errhandler);
```